# Создание нового экземпляра приложения после регистрации аккаунта

Tags: postgresql, nginx, devops, sh

Хочу сделать сервис, допустим хостится на [www.foo.ru](http://www.foo.ru)

В этом сервисе предполагается регистрация аккаунтов в основном компании (ип,юл)

После регистрации им нужно создать как бы экземпляр приложения со своей базой и со своим доменом, например введут имя компании «bar», после регистрации они попадают на домен [www.foo.bar.ru](http://www.foo.bar.ru) (или [www.bar.foo.ru](http://www.bar.foo.ru))

Видел немало сервисов именно так делают, как это можно сделать?

Почему нужно БД на каждый аккаунт: в основном чтобы каждая компания имела только свои данные, свои копии баз, дампы/миграции и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать следующую архитектуру по принципу виртуального хостинга:

1. Под каждый аккаунт создается отдельный пользователь в домашней папке которого локализуются данные его приложения
2. Вебсервер и сервер баз данных один на весь хост
3. Для каждого приложения на аккаунте создается свой пользователь и своя база данных

Для этого вы можете:

1. Зарегистрируйте домен foo.ru
2. Создайте скрипт добавляющий поддомен bar в DNS зону домена
3. Создайте скрипт, который добавит конфиг для поддомена
4. Создайте скрипт, который добавил бы на сервере пользователя и его домашнюю папку
5. Создайте скрипт, который создаст пользователя БД и саму БД и даст нужные права